# TypeScript abstract method using lambda/arrow function

Tags: lambda, typescript, abstract, arrow-functions, typescript1.6

I am using TypeScript 1.6 and would like to create an abstract class with an abstract method but use a lambda/arrow function in the concrete class.

Is this possible? The code shown below does not compile as it says

"Class 'Base' defines instance member function 'def', but extended class 'Concrete' defines it as instance member property"...

```
abstract class Base {
    abstract abc(): void;
    abstract def(): void;
}

class Concrete extends Base {
    private setting: boolean;

    public abc(): void  {
        this.setting = true;
    }

    public def = (): void => {
        this.setting = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding of Typescript specifications is that when you are declaring

```
public def = (): void => {
    this.setting = false;
}
```

You are actually declaring a `property` called `def` and not a `method` on the `Base` class.

Properties cannot (unfortunately IMHO) be abstracted in Typescript: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4669

Comment: That would certainly make the error message make a lot more sense. Unfortunately, my def method makes a call to a function that returns a promise and inside of the promise callback I need to refer to "this" hence the reason I want to use a lambda/arrow function.

Therefore I guess my only other option is to use var self = this; etc

Answer (score 2):

You can use an abstract property:

```
abstract class Base {    
    abstract def: () => void; // This is the abstract property
}

class Concrete extends Base {
    private setting: boolean;    

    public def = (): void => {
        this.setting = false;
    }
}

var myVar: Base = new Concrete();
myVar.def();
console.log((myVar as any).setting); // gives false
```

Comment: Cool, got the understanding now.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that starting typescript 2.0. In order to make that work you would need to declare a type for your arrow function

```
type defFuntion = () => void;
```

then declare

```
abstract class Base {
    abstract abc(): void;
    abstract readonly def: defFuntion;
}
```

[here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4669#ref-issue-124831866) is a reference for this feature